# Updating values in table based on ranges defined in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, update

I have two tables `definitions` and `history` with the following schema:

```
create table definitions (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    revision INT,
    majorVersion INT
  );
```

```
create table history (
   id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
   revision INT
   );
```

I want to update table `history` with another column `majorVersion` where the value ranges are defined in table `definitions`. For example, if records in `definitions` look like:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
|                  id                  |  revision |  majorVersion |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         2 |             1 |
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         4 |             2 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Then the updated table `history` should look something like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
|                  id                  |  revision |  majorVersion |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         1 |             1 |
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         2 |             1 |
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         3 |             2 |
| 9f717823-b9ca-4c7b-97f9-7770aaafb468 |         4 |             2 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/151aa) is a SQL Fiddle with a more number of rows.
The table `definitions` can contain potentially thousands of different `id` and multiple majorVersion. Subsequently, table `history` can contain can contains close to a million rows.

I want to make the query as fast and optimized as possible. One possible solution is to use something like this:

```
update history
set majorVersion = (
  select top 1 majorVersion
  from definitions
  where definitions.id = history.id
  and definitions.revision >= history.revision
  order by definitions.majorVersion
  )
where history.majorVersion = 0;
```

But the problem with this is that we are querying rows for every row in table `history` (which can be very large compared to `definitions`). Any suggestions on how to improve upon this?

Comment: There is no MySql server. There is MySQL and there is SQL Server but they are 2 different products.

Comment: The real question is "why are you rewriting history?"

Comment: Tables named "log" or "audit" or " history", are commonly write-once. Why are you updating it?

Comment: Its a feature demand. We have to update the history table to support a new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### One of two solutions

**solution 1**

*If you are able to split the work in two update statements, first update all the matching revisions*

```
UPDATE h
set h.majorVersion = d.majorVersion
FROM dbo.history h
INNER JOIN
dbo.definitions d
ON d.id = h.id
and d.revision = h.revision;
```

*Then use a `CTE` and windowing functions to update the `majorVersion`'s that are still 0 on the updated table*

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ID,revision, MAX(majorVersion) OVER (PARTITION BY Value2) as majorVersionUpdated,majorVersion
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, majorVersion,revision
        ,COUNT(case when majorVersion = 0 then NULL else majorVersion END) OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC,revision desc) AS Value2
    FROM dbo.history
) a
)

UPDATE CTE
SET majorVersion = majorVersionUpdated
WHERE majorVersion = 0;

SELECT * FROM dbo.history;
```

**An index like this could help**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_id_revision
on dbo.history(id,revision)
include(majorVersion)
```

**Result**

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.history;

id                                 revision majorVersion
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    1   1
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    2   1
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    3   1
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    4   2
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    5   2
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    6   3
9F717823-B9CA-4C7B-97F9-7770AAAFB468    7   3
546EF185-54AC-4AF8-82C6-61EFA3202353    1   1
546EF185-54AC-4AF8-82C6-61EFA3202353    2   2
546EF185-54AC-4AF8-82C6-61EFA3202353    3   2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2005/4)

---

**solution 2,  still two updates but with a `CROSS APPLY` and a self join. The self join is not ideal.**

*First update all the matching revisions*

```
UPDATE h
set h.majorVersion = d.majorVersion
FROM dbo.history h
INNER JOIN
dbo.definitions d
ON d.id = h.id
and d.revision = h.revision;
```

*Then do a self join to update the other majorVersions to the next one that is not 0*

```
UPDATE H 
SET h.majorVersion = h2.majorVersion
FROM dbo.history h
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN h2.majorVersion = 0 
           THEN NULL 
           ELSE h2.majorVersion END) as majorVersion 
FROM
dbo.history h2 
WHERE h2.id = h.id 
AND h2.revision >= h.revision
) h2
WHERE h.majorVersion = 0;


SELECT * from dbo.history;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d2005/3)

You would have to add `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... COMMIT TRANSACTION` to the updates if they have to be executed in one batch. The fastest way will depend on additional factors, such as your indexes & data, more than an example can show. **YMMV**

Comment: Here, the condition `where h.majorVersion = 0` will be evaluated after every update operation in `history` table?

Comment: @thebluebloo On further investigation this will probably not be a good way to go. Due to the many to many joins the Table spool / Join operators are going trough the roof.

Comment: @thebluebloo I added two other versions, the first one should be better. What SQL server version are you on?

Comment: We are using MySQL Server 2017.

Comment: Used something similar to solution 1. Thanks @Randi!

Comment: @thebluebloo great! Glad it helped and thanks for the feedback :)